# Open PopupWindow at top of the view

Tags: android, popupwindow, popupmenu

I want to have a show more button on click of which a popup should be opened with 3 options by default, but as per some logic then options would change ie. hide one of the options based on some condition.

[image]

I tried to add a popup menu:

```
popup = new PopupMenu(this, _showMore, GravityFlags.Top);

popup.MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.showMoreMenu, popup.Menu);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(someValue))
{
    popup.Menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.ABC1).SetVisible(false);
}

popup.MenuItemClick += Popup_MenuItemClick;
popup.Show();
```

But in this case, initially, when I have all 3 options the popup is displayed above the button as there is less space below the show more button. But if I hide one of the options then my popup menu opens up at the bottom of the button. I want my popup menu to always be opened above the anchor button.

Then I also tried

```
PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(this); // inflet your layout or diynamic add view

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.TestLayout, null, false);

TextView abc1 = (TextView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.abc1);
TextView abc2 = (TextView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.abc2);
TextView abc3 = (TextView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.abc3);
abc1.Click += abc1_Click;
abc2.Click += abc2_Click;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(somecondition))
{
    abc1.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
}
else
{
    abc2.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
}

popupWindow.Focusable = (true);
popupWindow.Width = (WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent);
popupWindow.Height = (WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent);
popupWindow.ContentView = (view);
popupWindow.SetBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.Transparent));

/*
//tried
var tttt= (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, Resource.Dimension._15sdp, Resources.DisplayMetrics);

//tried
int test=(int)(Resource.Dimension._15sdp * Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);

//tried
float scale = Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
test= (int)(Resource.Dimension._15sdp * scale + 0.5f);

//tried
var dp = Resource.Dimension._15sdp;
int pixel = (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, dp, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
*/

popupWindow.ShowAsDropDown(_showMore, -220, -570); <-- fixed offset which works for 3 options
```

The above code works but I have set fixed offset values which I assume will not render it correctly on different resolutions of the phone and also when I hide one of the options from the menu.

I also tried using ListPopupWindow but the same issue of setting the location. Can anybody please help me in setting offsets dynamically.

Comment: Have you checked  _setDropDownGravity_ and _setPromptPosition_ for `ListPopupWindow` ?

Comment: what should I set for setPromptPosition and  setDropDownGravity ?

Comment: Doesn't work with  `listPopupWindow.PromptPosition =0; listPopupWindow.SetDropDownGravity(GravityFlags.Top);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could it work like this :

```
int[] location = new int[2];
_showMore.getLocationOnScreen(location);
popupWindow.showAtLocation(_showMore,Gravity.NO_GRAVITY,location[0], location[1] - popupWindow.getHeight());
```

Comment: What is location?

Comment: popupWindow.getHeight returns -2, I read somewhere that we won't get the height or width of the view, which hasn't been drawn on the screen. And the popup ovelaps the button _showmore.

Comment: yes，i would like to tell you add "view.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED,MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED); "

Comment: Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks. It worked, but can you please help me giving some margin at the right for the popup. Now the popup comes touching the screen at right. I want to add some space.

Comment: I'm sorry I just saw the message.You could change "location[0]“ to "getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() -value - view.getMeasuredWidth();” ,the value is the space you want to add.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
fun showPopupAbove(anchor: View) {
        viewAnchor = anchor
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchor)
        } else {
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(anchor, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0)
        }
        measureSizeThenUpdatePopupWindowPosition()
    }


private fun measureSizeThenUpdatePopupWindowPosition() {
        val viewTreeObserver = rootView.viewTreeObserver
        if (!viewTreeObserver.isAlive) {
            return
        }
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                rootView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                val anchorRect = getRectFromView(viewAnchor)
                // calculate x,y position for display popup window above/below..ect anchor view
                var popupWinDownPositionX = (anchorRect.centerX() - rootView.width.toFloat() / 6).toInt()
                var popupWinDownPositionY = anchorRect.top

                // anchor view close to left
                if (popupWinDownPositionX < 0) {
                    popupWinDownPositionX = 0
                }
                // anchor view close to top
                if (popupWinDownPositionY < 0) {
                    popupWinDownPositionY = 0
                }
                // anchor view close to right
                if (popupMayExceedsTheScreen(popupWinDownPositionX,
                        rootView.width)) {
                    popupWinDownPositionX = (Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels - rootView.width.toFloat()).toInt()
                }
                popupWindow.update(popupWinDownPositionX, popupWinDownPositionY,
                    rootView.width, rootView.height)
                updateImageArrowMargin(popupWinDownPositionX)
            }
        })
    }
```

You can modify the value of `popupWinDownPositionX` and `popupWinDownPositionY` to fit with your purpose

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @LeoZhu [@LeoZhu's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53739168/1650891). I managed to get it working using the following code

```
PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(this); // inflet your layout or diynamic add view

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.TestLayout, null, false);

TextView abc1 = (TextView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.abc1);
TextView abc2 = (TextView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.abc2);
TextView abc3 = (TextView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.abc3);
abc1.Click += GenerateQR_Click;
abc2.Click += PrintQR_Click;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(somecode))
{
abc1.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
}
else
{
abc2.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
}

int[] location = new int[2];
_showMore.GetLocationOnScreen(location);

popupWindow.Focusable = (true);
popupWindow.Width = (WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent);
popupWindow.Height = (WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent);
popupWindow.ContentView = (view);
popupWindow.SetBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.Transparent));

view.Measure(View.MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified),
View.MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified));

int yOffset = location[1] - (int)(view.MeasuredHeight );

popupWindow.ShowAtLocation(_showMore, GravityFlags.NoGravity, location[0], yOffset);
```